# В каких случаях искользовать SSR (server side rendering)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssr

Прочитал уже довольно много инфы про ssr и csr, но всё ещё не могу понять нужно ли мне на проекте использовать ssr.

Frontend: React, Redux
Backend:  Node.js, express, postgress SQL,

На проекте будет присутствовать много медиа контента, который в последствии будет изменяться на сервере (blur картинок и т.д.).

помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Например до сих пор не все поисковые роботы могут исполнять JS(Яндекс и Google умеют, DuckDuckGo - нет), поэтому они видят SPA, как страницу без контента, соответсвенно ни о какой выдаче на первой странице и речи быть не может. Это, наверное, самый важный фактор.  Дальше идет уже ускорение рендеринга на слабых девайсах; какой-нибудь старенький телефон на android будет рендерить гораздо медленее, чем сервер, который выдаст уже готовый html.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ